# Issue with MacBook Pro not able to select screenshots for upload

Tags: icloud, macos-catalina, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have a Macbook Pro that I bought to do software development with, for both Android and iOS, it is a fairly new MacBook with dual core 2.7 Ghz CPU, 8GB of RAM, and an SSD drive that is superfast. It runs the most current MacOS, Catalina.

I have been working recently with Android Studio on it, and encountered an issue that I wanted to do a forum post on, I took a screenshot of the Java code in my Android application I am working on, and was going to upload it to iCloud photos.

But the file selector for iCloud photos will  not let me select ANY files, including not letting me select image files. All the files are greyed out, and the CHOOSE button is greyed out also. I have no problems uploading the image files to my Microsoft OneDrive Cloud. Note screenshot.

[image: Macbook Pro]

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found a partial workaround to this issue. Find the screenshot in FINDER, then double click on it to open it in PREVIEW, then choose the SHARE button to share it to iCloud Photos. Then the screen shot image will be in iCloud Photos. Still would like to know a solution to the original problem in the Post. Thanks.